# Laravel 5.x (master) Form Request validation response as a json

Tags: php, angularjs, json, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to return Form Request erros as a json?

I am making an API to AngularJS, and I am having problems with the error flags

Here is my rules:

```
class CreateProductRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
    return [
            'code'=>'required|unique:products',
            'style'=>'required|max:12',
            'measure'=>'required|max:12',
        ];
    }
```

This is the response from CreateProductRequest

```
{
    code: [0: "Code is required"],
    style:[0: "Style is required"],
    measure:[ 0: "Measure is required"]
}
```

I want the same result as $validator->errors()->all() on the controller, like this:

```
"messages": [
    "Code is required",
    "Style is required",
    "Measure is required"
]
```

How can I get this result from Form Request?

Laravel version: master

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Form Request validation response as JSON" and "I want the same result as $validator->errors()->all() on the controller"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form Request errors are already returned as json for AJAX requests. But to achieve the structure you want, you have to override the response function in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php

Copy the function from there and paste it in Request class in app/Http/Requests/Request.php. Change the following line:

```
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
```

to this:

```
    $messages = array();
    foreach ($errors as $element) {
        foreach ($element as $element_error) {
            $messages[] = $element_error;
        }
    }
    $response['messages'] = $messages;
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    return new JsonResponse($response, 200);
```

Instead of 200, you can return any other status code you are using already, maybe from 4xx series.
Add this at the top of this file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you for your help. The only thing I change was this line `$messages[] = $element_error;` to `$messages[] = ["message" => $element_error];`, to make it works with angular ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return $validator->errors()->all()->toJson();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but @Vikas answer was the correct one, I have to override the response from FormRequest class.